# Socket.io set cookie with nginx

Tags: node.js, cookies, nginx, socket.io, engine.io

My app architecture is here.

- front-server 3000 - domain.com, serve files to browser
- api-server 3001 - api.domain.com
- socket-server 3003 - io.domain.com

In dev mode, socket request have all http request cookies,

But in production mode with nginx (down to conf),

socket cookie just have a cookie **io**

- In dev
  [image]
- In prod
  [image: In prod]

This is nginx conf(part of socket server).

```
server {
  server_name io.domain.com;

  location / {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header X-Forwared-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3003;
  }
  location /socket.io/ {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header X-Forwared-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3003;
  }
}
```

Here is socket client

```
const io = require('socket.io-client');
let socket;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  socket = io.connect('http://io.domain.com/noti');
} else {
  socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3003/noti');
}

module.exports = socket;
```

In development env, it works well but in production mode because of the problem, I can't retrieve user values.

I need to use cookie value sessionId, token to auth, but two cookie values are disappeared.

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of all, Set cookie with domain.

For example in node js,

```
res.setCookie({...
    domain: 'domain.com'
});
```

And in nginx conf,

```
proxy_cookie_domain io.domain.com domain.com
```